# Upload images to Active directory using c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, active-directory

I am using this part of code to upload image to AD using C# which works fine . but line   directoryObject.Properties("thumbnailPhoto").Clear() takes longer time is any way I can reduce the time taken by that command?

```
           Using directory As New DirectoryEntry(address)
            Using searcher As New DirectorySearcher(directory)

                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto")
                searcher.Filter = "cn=" & targetUser

                Dim domainUser As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne()

                Using directoryObject As DirectoryEntry = domainUser.GetDirectoryEntry()
                    directoryObject.Properties("thumbnailPhoto").Clear()
                    directoryObject.Properties("thumbnailPhoto").Add(imgToByteArray)
                    directoryObject.CommitChanges()
                    Return True
                End Using

            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: It depends on Size of image, or else try in new thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use task factory and the blocking of the operation will not interfere with you UI:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                       directoryObject.Properties("thumbnailPhoto").Clear()
                       directoryObject.Properties("thumbnailPhoto").Add(imgToByteArray)
                       directoryObject.CommitChanges()           
                      End Sub))
```